# Frequently VS Recently Used Emoji's?

Tags: iphone, emoji

My iPhone used to show me my **frequently** used Emojis, which was super helpful. I guess after one of the updates though, my phone started showing me my **recently** used Emojis instead. It can be helpful but I would like to see my frequent ones instead, so is there a way to switch that? Or am I stuck with recently used?

Comment: Are  you now on 9.2.1?   My 9.2 still says Frequently.

Comment: Mine still says Frequently on iOS 11.2.6 could it be you were using a third party keyboard that changed?